# How do i use a shared pointer in this context?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I know a little about how shared pointers function. At work, we have this existing piece of code which passes around a shared_pointer object which is intended to act as the root node of a tree that we are building.
PS. This is legacy, undocumented code. So we don't know why it was written like this.

```
struct Object
{
     vector<shared_ptr<Object>> children;
     string name;
}
```

```
void f1(shared_ptr<Object>node)
{
     f2(node);
}
```

```
void class1::f2(shared_ptr<Object>node)    // specialization 1, works as expected
{
     shared_ptr<Object> n1 = make_shared<Object>();
     node->children.push_back(n1);
}
```

```
void class2::f2(shared_ptr<Object> node)    // specialization 2
{
     shared_ptr<Object> n1 = make_shared<Object>(); 
     buildTree(n1, node);
}
```

```
void buildTree(shared_ptr<Object> n1, shared_ptr<Object>rootNode)
{

      // builds a tree recursively using n1 and adding more nodes as necessary
      shared_ptr<Object> inFunctionCreatedNode;

      // if root node found during node addition, assign this node to the rootNode parameter
      rootNode = inFunctionCreatedNode;   // this does not seem to work correctly
}
```

The function f2 belongs to an abstract class this is specialized for different applications. In the cases where this works, what is done is a simple addition directly to the shared_ptr object. The function specialization that I'm working on now is more complex, I don't know where my tree starts and hence I cannot directly follow the same scheme. So, I wrote class2::f2 which calls another function where I assign the root node of the tree I am building (when it is found) to the shared_ptr object that I originally started with.

The problem with this is that the node assignment is temporary, i.e., the nodes added to the shared_ptr in buildtree() go out of scope upon leaving class2::f2. My solution to this was to traverse the tree from buildtree() (local shared_ptr used to point to root node of tree now) and create a new set of nodes that I directly assign to the parameter rootNode. In other words, I follow the method in class1::f2(shared_ptr).

Can someone explain why this happens- and potentially something that would shed more light on these pointers? The resources I find online don't seem to be touching upon such an issue.

Edit 1: Updated vector definition

Edit 2: There's a pretty good chance I know what's wrong-
in buildtree(), I'm essentially letting go of the shared_ptr object that I created in the outer scope and replacing it with a node that has a local scope. The fact that my shared_ptr variable exists in an outer scope has nothing to do with scope of the object it is pointing to. Does that make sense?

Comment: I don't understand how you are pushing a `std::shared_ptr<Object>`onto a `std::vector<Object>` in `void class1::f2()`.

Comment: Also using `std::shared_ptr` for trees sounds a bit fishy to me. Are all the nodes truly shared?

Comment: @Galik Thanks for pointing that out. Was a typo on my vector definition. 

As for sharing, what do you mean? Also, can you check edit 2 and see if that makes sense?

Comment: BTW,  you are correct in your `Edit 2` assumption. You break the sharing when you assign a new shared pointer to your local copy.

Comment: Great, thanks for the assist!

Comment: Regarding sharing, how many objects are responsible for the destruction of each node? In a tree it is usually just one (the parent).

Comment: The "shared" of `shared_ptr` means shared ownership, not shared access.   Unless you have multiple places that *own* the data and can't know which one should ultimately be responsible for destroying it, you don't want `shared_ptr` -- you almost never want shared_ptr.

Comment: Its just the parent, as you mentioned.

Comment: Then I would consider using `std::unique_ptr`. It is more efficient, less error-prone and more expressive of the intent.

Comment: This is a very useful guide: https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#rr-summary-smartptrs

Comment: @Galik I do agree, a unique_ptr would better serve the purpose. Its a lot of changes to make in the code base and not really worth the effort.

Comment: Sure, if it aint broke, don't fix it :-)

Comment: @xaxxon Could you elaborate on the difference? I am not able to decouple the two. My understanding of shared ownership is that we can extend lifetime of objects.  Short of working in MT world, I cannot think of a good use for shared_ptr

Comment: Imagine a direct acyclic graph instead of a tree. (A DAG is similar to a tree but multiple parent nodes may share the same children.)

Comment: @speed_of_light ownership means who knows when the object should go away.  In most situations there is one logical place in which the lifetime of the object is known to be over, and that's when you use a unique_ptr.   Only if there are multiple things which each require the object yet either can be done with the object first so either has to be able to destroy it if the other owner is already gone do you use shared_ptr.